# How to represent sparse RDBS columns in PostgreSQL with JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

Assume we have columns in rational db (table) for measured characteristics: A,B,C,D,...,Z. Each of them has 3 columns: name,value,error. Samples are rows, one sample has one or zero measurement for each characteristic. Data for A and B columns are 90% filled, but C,D,...,Z are very rare - sparse columns (approximately 10% of cells contain not null values in each).

What is the best way to store these data in PostgreSQL with JSON?

My variants (new table has 2 columns: serial ID and JSON)

1. Store JSON array of sample in one cell (one original row matches one new row).
2. Break JSON array of sample into several rows (one array element in one row; thus, one original row matches a few new rows).
3. Use rational columns :)

Example: 2 original rows provide these JSON strings:

```
----------row 1----------
[
    {
        "name" : "A",
        "value" : 3.300000,
        "err" : 1.200000,
    },
    {
        "name" : "B",
        "value" : 730.000000,
        "err" : 112.000000,
    },
    {
        "name" : "E",
        "value" : 22.600000,
        "err" : 4.700000,
    },
    {
        "name" : "H",
        "value" : 58.300000,
        "err" : 11.100000,
    }
]
----------row 2----------
[
    {
        "name" : "A",
        "value" : 2.100000,
        "err" : 1.400000,
    },
    {
        "name" : "J",
        "value" : 266.000000,
        "err" : 65.000000,
    },
    {
        "name" : "K",
        "value" : 14.700000,
        "err" : 3.800000,
    }
 ]
```

Which one should I use?

And how to import this dataset to PostgreSQL if I have text file with records (JSON array for each row of original table) as mentioned in example?

Answer (score -1):

Can you be clear about what problem you are trying to solve with this approach?

A null value in a column only uses 1 bit of space.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html

It seems unlikely that your JSON (or JSONB) column is going to use less space, and it is going to cost you in terms of code clarity and ability to use conventional query techniques.

I would go for a regular table design, and use the relational database as a relational database, unless doing otherwise solves an identifiable problem.

Comment: > A null value in a column only uses 1 bit of space.

This depends on how many columns you have.

Comment: Sure, it can be a bit more, but it's not like one byte per column of anything.

Answer (score -1):

## Import:

Import your data as plain text first using [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html), in case it's not in valid JSON format (which is the case here).
You can use [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html) for some basic cleaning, then parse it with a simple [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). If the file is not easily reachable from the db, you can look into [psql `\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html#:%7E:text=current%20database%20connection.-,%5Ccopy,-%7B%20table%20%5B%20(%20column_list%20)%20%5D%20%7D%20from) as well as its [PGAdmin wrapper](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.6/import_export_data.html)

```sql
create table public.measurement_samples_raw (sample_row text);

/* /home/username/measurement_samples.json:
[{"name":"A","value":3.300000,"err":1.200000,},{"name":"B","value":730.000000,"err":112.000000,},{"name":"E","value":22.600000,"err":4.700000,},{"name":"H","value":58.300000,"err":11.100000,}]
[{"name":"A","value":2.100000,"err":1.400000,},{"name":"J","value":266.000000,"err":65.000000,},{"name":"K","value":14.700000,"err":3.800000,}] */
copy public.measurement_samples_raw (sample_row) 
    from '/home/your_username/measurement_samples.json';

update public.measurement_samples_raw set 
    sample_row = regexp_replace(
                    '{"top_key":'||sample_row||'}', --unnamed lists aren't supported, so adding a key and wrapping in {...}
                    ',\s*}', '}',--pattern and replacement to remove trailing commas
                    'g' --forces the function to replace all instances of the pattern
                    );

alter table public.measurement_samples_raw 
    add column sample_id serial,--so that each measurement sample has an ID
    add column sample_row_jsonb jsonb;
    
update public.measurement_samples_raw 
    set sample_row_jsonb=sample_row::jsonb;
```

## Storage:

You can normalize the structure and populate it by extraction using [json type functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING)

```sql
drop table if exists public.measurement_samples;
create table public.measurement_samples (
    id    serial,
    name  char(1),
    value numeric,
    err   numeric,
    constraint measurement_samples_pk primary key (id, name) --I assume you don't want >=2 values for characteristic 'A' in a single measurement row
);

insert into public.measurement_samples (id, name, value, err)
select  sample_id,
        (single_measurement_in_sample->>'name')::text,
        (single_measurement_in_sample->>'value')::numeric,
        (single_measurement_in_sample->>'err')::numeric
from (        
    select  sample_id,
            json_array_elements(
                sample_row::json->'top_key'
            ) as single_measurement_in_sample
    from public.measurement_samples_raw
    ) raw_input;
```

Which gives you a gapless structure:

```sql
table public.measurement_samples;
-- id | name |   value    |    err
------+------+------------+------------
--  1 | A    |   3.300000 |   1.200000
--  1 | B    | 730.000000 | 112.000000
--  1 | E    |  22.600000 |   4.700000
--  1 | H    |  58.300000 |  11.100000
--  2 | A    |   2.100000 |   1.400000
--  2 | J    | 266.000000 |  65.000000
--  2 | K    |  14.700000 |   3.800000
--(7 rows)
```

Which you can rearrange to your needs, without wasting space, at the cost of performance - unless you make the view [materialized](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-creatematerializedview.html):

```sql
create view public.v_measurement_samples as
select  id, 
        sum(value) filter (where name='A') as "A_value",
        sum(err) filter (where name='A') as "A_err",
        sum(value) filter (where name='B') as "B_value",
        sum(err) filter (where name='B') as "B_err",
        sum(value) filter (where name='C') as "C_value",
        sum(err) filter (where name='C') as "C_err",
        sum(value) filter (where name='D') as "D_value",
        sum(err) filter (where name='D') as "D_err",
        sum(value) filter (where name='E') as "E_value",
        sum(err) filter (where name='E') as "E_err"
from    public.measurement_samples
group by id
order by id;

--table public.v_measurement_samples;
-- id | A_value  |  A_err   |  B_value   |   B_err    | C_value | C_err | D_value | D_err |  E_value  |  E_err
------+----------+----------+------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+----------
--  1 | 3.300000 | 1.200000 | 730.000000 | 112.000000 |         |       |         |       | 22.600000 | 4.700000
--  2 | 2.100000 | 1.400000 |            |            |         |       |         |       |           |
--(2 rows)
```

Working [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f48ee144d49b167c1821d5ad8761ec56) example.

Comment: The normalisation to treat the `name` as a value is fine (it's close to an entity-attribute-value EAV model), unless you want to efficiently run queries comparing or selecting values within a single serial id, for which the materialised view is likely to be essential. If the MV proves to be important, why not just save the data like that in first place? So it feels like either (i) use the EAV model, or (ii) save it as a regular relational table.

Comment: I agree. The initial structure is supposed to address the problem of sparse input data, while being an easy target to import into, pretty much directly reflecting the presented input layout. The end of my answer points away from that initial structure without assuming too much about how the data will be processed further - it's not specified by the question but would logically be the next problem to look into.